# DateTimeDropdown not displaying correctly as shown in the ADB2C document

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am trying out samples for ADB2C custom policies and used DateTimeDropdown for dateOfBirth attribute.
declared the claimType as

```
<ClaimType Id="dateOfBirth">
            <DisplayName>Date of Birth</DisplayName>
            <DataType>date</DataType>
            <AdminHelpText>The user's date of birth.</AdminHelpText>
            <UserHelpText>Your date of birth.</UserHelpText>
            <UserInputType>DateTimeDropdown</UserInputType>
            <PredicateValidationReference Id="CustomDateRange" />
        </ClaimType>
```

I have a ClaimsProvider called - **Sample User Input Collection Technical Profiles** with technical profile with Id - **UserInformationCollector**

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="UserInformationCollector">
                <DisplayName>
                    Collect Sample User Input Technical Profile
                </DisplayName>
                <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
                <Metadata>
                    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">SelfAssertedContentDefinition</Item>
                    <Item Key="LookupNotFound">The provided email address was not from a valid company.</Item>
                </Metadata>
                <DisplayClaims>
                    <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" Required="true" />
                    <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" Required="true" />
                    <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="dateOfBirth" Required="true" />
                    <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="accountType" Required="true" />
                    <DisplayClaim DisplayControlReferenceId="emailControl" />
                    <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
                </DisplayClaims>
                <OutputClaims>
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="dateOfBirth" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="accountType" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="validDomains" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="domain" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="domainStatus" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="passwordText" />
                </OutputClaims>
                <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
                    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="CheckCompanyDomain">
                        <Preconditions>
                            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
                                <Value>accountType</Value>
                                <Value>company</Value>
                                <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
                            </Precondition>
                        </Preconditions>
                    </ValidationTechnicalProfile>

                    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="HttpCompanyDomainsCollector">
                        <Preconditions>
                            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
                                <Value>accountType</Value>
                                <Value>company</Value>
                                <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
                            </Precondition>
                        </Preconditions>


                    </ValidationTechnicalProfile>
                    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="PasswordCopier" />
                </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            </TechnicalProfile>
```

and finally calling this technical profile in the default UserJourney.
I did not see any code to do any modifications for making the UI look differently. But the DateTimeDropdown field looks bad in my screen. What is that I am missing? How can I make it look better?
Link: [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claimsschema)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dropdown looks exactly the same as the documentation?

That's the default look and feel.

You can't alter the UI for date via config.

You can always roll your own with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The `templates/AzureBlue/selfAsserted.cshtml` applies css to:

```
id= cpiminternal_dateOfBirth / cpiminternal_dateOfBirth_year / cpiminternal_dateOfBirth_month / cpiminternal_dateOfBirth_day
```

[b2c dob correctly displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ytggt.png)

So you can either set `<ClaimType Id="dateOfBirth">` to `<ClaimType Id="cpiminternal_dateOfBirth">` or change the template `/selfAsserted.cshtml` and add custom content definition.